# SPOTBUGS SUPPRESSION

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spotbugs, suppression

I want to suppress an error that I got by running `mvn spotbugs:check`

I have a file named `requestBodyDto.java` in my code as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * Data Transfer Object (DTO) representing the request body.
 */
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestBodyDto {

    /**
     * Reference of the sender.
     */
    @JsonProperty("sender_reference")
    private String senderReference;

    /**
     * Type of the message.
     */
    @JsonProperty("message_type")
    private String messageType;

    /**
     * Sender information.
     */
    private String sender;

    /**
     * Receiver information.
     */
    private String receiver;

    /**
     * Network information.
     */
    @JsonProperty("network_info")
    private NetworkInfo networkInfo;

    /**
     * Payload of the message.
     */
    private String payload;

    /**
     * Network information nested class.
     */
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class NetworkInfo {

        /**
         * Priority of the network.
         */
        private NetworkPriority networkPriority;

        /**
         * Unique End-to-End Transaction Reference (UETR).
         */
        private String uetr;

        /**
         * Delivery monitoring status.
         */
        private DeliveryMonitoring deliveryMonitoring;

        /**
         * Indicates if the message is a possible duplicate.
         */
        private boolean possibleDuplicate;

        /**
         * Identifier for validation.
         */
        private String validationIdentifier;

        /**
         * Identifier for the service type.
         */
        private String serviceTypeIdentifier;
    }

    /**
     * Enum representing network priority.
     */
    public enum NetworkPriority {
        /**
         * Normal network priority.
         */
        Normal,

        /**
         * Urgent network priority.
         */
        Urgent,

        /**
         * System-level network priority.
         */
        System
    }


    /**
     * Enum representing delivery monitoring status.
     */
    public enum DeliveryMonitoring {
        /**
         * No delivery monitoring.
         */
        None,

        /**
         * Monitoring for non-delivery.
         */
        NonDelivery,

        /**
         * Monitoring for both non-delivery and delivery.
         */
        NonDeliveryAndDelivery,

        /**
         * Monitoring for successful delivery.
         */
        Delivery
    }
```

On running `mvn spotbugs:check` I am receiving the following error :

[ERROR] new com.guardianlife.connector.client.messaging.dto.RequestBodyDto(String, String, String, String, RequestBodyDto$NetworkInfo, String) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into RequestBodyDto.networkInfo [com.guardianlife.connector.client.messaging.dto.RequestBodyDto] At RequestBodyDto.java:[line 13] EI_EXPOSE_REP2

I have written a `spotbugsSuppression.xml` file that suppresses two errors :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <!-- Suppress SpotBugs warnings for internal representation exposure -->
    <Match>
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP" />
        <Class name="com.guardianlife.connector.client.messaging.dto.RequestBodyDto" />
        <Method name="getNetworkInfo" />
    </Match>

    <Match>
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP2" />
        <Class name="com.guardianlife.connector.client.messaging.dto.RequestBodyDto" />
        <Method name="setNetworkInfo" />
    </Match>

</FindBugsFilter>
```

I am not able to suppress the above error, I have tried every possible way of doing that but I am not able to do so. What can I try next?

Comment: Does `mvn spotbugs:check` just write errors to `/dev/stdout`? If so, can you write a pipe that does some custom filtering? So it would be called `mvn spotbugs:check | errorpipe.sh`.